# Improving my Database Design for future scalability

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

Well, I am working on a project which might involve thousands of users & I don't have much experience in databases especially when it involves relationships between entities.

Let me explain my scenario. First there's an User who can login into our system using his credentials. We have a module in our system, which will enable him to create Projects. So that brings a relationship between User table & Projects table.

Now there's another module, namely Team Creation Module, it does what it says. Out of the list of available members, he can pick who he likes and add them to a team. So there are tables for that Members & Team. Furthermore, a member can be a part of many teams and a team can have many members & a "User" can be member as well.

I have a designed the database myself but I am not sure if it is good or bad one. Moreover, I would really appreciate if someone can point me to good tutorials which shows how to insert or update into tables involving relationships.

Here's my design till now:

[image]

**Update**

After a discussion with someone on IRC, I came up with a revised design. I merged "User" & "Members" table as User is also a Member.

[image]

My question still remains the same, Am I on right track?

Comment: Yes, you're basically on track. However, can a member really only be a part of one and only one project?  Shouldn't there be a many-to-many relationship there? You should also have natural keys defined. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key

Comment: @JonBoulineau That's an interesting question (I didn't think of it before; It's kinda thought provoking on if there should a many to many relationship between Members and Projects as well). Well a Member can create many projects & can be a part of other many projects too (I guess including his project as well).

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you're thinking long-term, but your solution won't work long-term.

This is not the first time this sort of thing has been tried before. Rely on the wisdom of those that have messed up before. Read data modeling pattern books.

Abstract and Normalize. That's how you get to a good long-term solution.

At least read up on The Party Model. A group and individual are actually the same (abstract) thing.

Put actually different things in different tables. An Address and Member don't belong in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

"Am I on the right track" is not a useful question - we have no way of telling, because it depends on where you are headed.

A couple of things:

- it's a good idea to name the relation columns after the relationship. For instance, in the first diagram, the "owner" of the project should not be called users_user_id - that's meaningless. Call it "owner_id" or something that meaningfully describes the relationship between the project and members table.
- in the second diagram, you appear to have a "many to many" relationship between members and projects in the members table - but there's no efficient way of storing the id of more than one project in the members table. You need to factor that out into a joining table - projects_members, for instance, just like you did with teams_members.
- the "teams_members" table has a primary key called tm_id. A purist would tell you this is wrong - the unique identifier for that table should be the combination of member_id and team_id. You don't need another unique identifier - and in fact it's harmful, because you must guarantee uniqueness of the member_id and team_id combination.

As Neil says, you probably want to start reading up on this. I can recommend 'Database Systems: Design, Implementation, and Management' by Coronel et al.

Comment: Regarding the third point, if I want to do what you suggested, how can I do that?